# Append issues with Packery.js

Tags: javascript, packery

I am trying to append the existing page content on 'click' to the end of the grid, but with no luck. The example in the docs on Codepen creates a `div`, whereas I am trying to pull the data from the existing grid item using `packery.('getItemElements')` and while it returns an array of HTML elements, when I append to the grid, the original items move and the old ones disappear but not before Packery has already placed the elements after, leaving a bit white hole.

This is what I have so far:

```
grid = $('.grid');
grid.packery({
    gutter: 10,
    itemSelector: '.grid-item',
    isHorizontal: true
});

$('.grid-wrapper .navigation .next').on('click', function() {

    var newGridContent = [];
    var currentContent = $('.grid').packery('getItemElements');

    for (var i = 0; i < currentContent.length; i++) {
        var newGridItem = currentContent[i];
        newGridContent.push(newGridItem);
    };
    grid.append(newGridContent);
    grid.packery('appended', newGridContent);

});
```

You can see this live here, on the main grid carousel at the top:

http://johnpett.com/youraudience/

Comment: Sorry - where is grid defined?

Comment: Updated question for you. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone stumbles on this, here is my solution:

```
var currentContent;

$('.grid-wrapper .navigation .next').on('click', function() {

    currentContent = $('.grid').packery('getItemElements');

    var elems = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        var elem = getItemElement(i);
        elems.push(elem);
    };

    $('.grid').append(elems);

    $('.grid').packery('appended', elems);

    $('.grid').animate({
        "left": "-=500px"
    });

});

function getItemElement(i) {
    var elem = document.createElement('div');
    var itemImage = currentContent[i].style.backgroundImage;
    var itemOuterHTML = currentContent[i].outerHTML;
    elem.style.backgroundImage = itemImage;
    elem.innerHTML = itemOuterHTML;
    return elem;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going on a hunch here but will update with more if this doesn't work...

```
var p_grid = grid.packery({
    gutter: 10,
    itemSelector: '.grid-item',
    isHorizontal: true
});

$('.grid-wrapper .navigation .next').on('click', function () {

    var newGridContent = [];
    var currentContent = $('.grid').packery('getItemElements');

    for (var i = 0; i < currentContent.length; i++) {
        var newGridItem = currentContent[i];
        newGridContent.push(newGridItem);
    };
    p_grid.append(newGridContent).packery('appended', newGridContent);

});
```

Comment: That appends fine, but I still have a white gap where the previous content was.

Comment: try adding `.packery()` to the end of that last statement

Comment: That animates the append to the left, and removes existing content - http://johnpett.com/youraudience/. I have also tried appending to the grid wrapper that the packery was assigned to, but this doesn't work either.

Comment: I still see `grid` defined as the jQuery object in your js... note the `p_grid` is the packery object.

Comment: Sorry, yes, changed that, but now get: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'packery' of undefined

Comment: You commented out this: `/* grid navigation */
  // var p_grid = grid.packery({
  //     gutter: 10,
  //     itemSelector: '.grid-item',
  //     isHorizontal: true
  // });`

Comment: I did, I was trying to figure something else out! I have uncommented now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70982/discussion-between-tomanow-and-johnrobertpett).